# Pivot Table Calculated field only on Label/Subtotal Rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a calculated field in a pivot table returning the running total of my period totals (Ending balance of each period). When my period Field in entirely collapsed, it looks great, but when I expand a period to look at individual transactions the calculated field is on all of those rows as well.

I'm ideally looking to see if anyone has a purely pivot settings solution.
I've tried using VBA to clear the contents when the table is updated but run into error `1004 - use field list option to modify pivot table`.
I'm currently making the range text white by finding all the required cells then `Rng.font.TintAndShade = 0`.
I'd also like to keep this WB ".xlsx" format so it's easier for me to send to coworkers.

Pivot Collapsed:
[image: Pivot table collapsed]

Pivot Expanded:
[image: Pivot table expanded]

Calculated field settings:
[image: Settings]

Comment: If you add your table to the Data Model then this can be achieved quite easily using a measure within Power Pivot; no VBA necessary.

Comment: Thanks @JosWoolley, I've spent years building report generators with VBA, and now is time to learn pivot tables. Is there any additional information you can offer on: what the "data model" is and, where I can find articles/documentation related to it, any articles directly related to this problem.

Comment: I can't offer you any links beyond those that would come up as a result of some simple internet searches. I might be able to help you with the specific DAX for the measure you would require, however.

Comment: Okay thanks, what's a DAX?

Comment: It's a language used by various applications, including Power Pivot.

Comment: Okay, I've gone down the rabbit hole. I've never used Power Pivot nor DAX, nor the data model before. This may take longer than I have to learn for this specific project so I will likely stick with just changing text color with vba and dedicate some serious time to learning to use Power Pivot. I'll come back if/when I run into specific issues with DAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future solution thanks to @JosWoolley:

- Enable Power Pivot
- Import table into the Data Model
- Use DAX formulas to generate the expected result